# Как воспроизвести звук в Android?

Tags: java, android, аудио

Как воспроизвести звуковой файл из приложения написанного на JAVA для Android, допустим по нажатию кнопки?

```
public void onclick(View v) 
{
    //Проиграть музыку(фанфары)
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {     
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(Test.this, R.raw.mysound);   
                mp.start();
        }.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Скажи пожалуйста, куда запихнуть информацию о том какой файл воспроизвести?

Comment: res/raw/mysound.mp3 ?? какую информацию? это и есть ид файла, который надо воспроизвести

Comment: Все спасибо, разобрался)

Comment: Тема не раскрыта, куда класть аудио файлы, зачем создавать новый поток...

Comment: Аудио файлы нужно класть в директорию raw, по умолчанию её нет в Android Studio, её нужно создать, добавив новую директорию с именем raw в разделе res. Если не создать новый поток, то воспроизведение будет происходить в главном потоке, что произведет к зависанию UI, а далее к вылету приложения.